# nodejs request - toString failed - buffer size issue for big files (maxBufferSize)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-request

I'm requesting a big file with 150K records but it throws 'toString failed' error. [nodejs/node#3175](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/3175) says it's because of maxBufferSize. Request works well for 200 records but its an external api and the requirement is to get all records at once.[no pagination there :( ]
Is there any way to set buffersize for this request?

I already asked this question [here](https://github.com/request/request/issues/2067)

EDIT:

```
request("http://www.site-containing-big-data/api",
        function (error, response, body) {
            console.log('got something to show');
            if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                resolve(body);
            }else if(error){
                reject(error);
            }
        });
```

but nothing shows in console other than `toString failed` message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it. It was an xml file and I was trying to process it directly. Now I'm first saving in a file and then using `xml-stream` to process each object one by one.

```
request.get("http://www.site-containing-big-data/api" )
        .on('error', function(errReq) {
            console.log('error while reading from big site : ', errReq);

        }).on('end', function(){
            console.log('got from big site, now processing');
            var XmlStream = require('xml-stream') ;
            var stream=fs.createReadStream('bigfile.xml');
            xml = new XmlStream(stream);
            xml.on('endElement: item', function(item) {//item is a node. structure is <items><item></item><item></item></items>
                //do something here
            });
            xml.on('end', function(){
                // when processing finished for all objects/items in that file
                });
            });
        })
        .pipe(fs.createWriteStream('bigfile.xml'));
```